# why does this not loop through drop down list

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have this code which should loop through each item in a drop down list. When the next item is selected it should update the main worksheet. Then Create a pdf of the worksheet. What happens is it creates a pdf NAMED after each item but the contents don't change from the first item. I basically have 50 pdfs of item 1 called 50 different things. Whereas I want 50 pdfs of 50 things named after each thing? any help appreciated

```
Sub Create_pdf_pack()

 Dim inputRange As Range
 Dim c As Range
 Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("AD5").Validation.Formula1)
 For Each c In inputRange
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    fileName:="C:\test\" & c.Value, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: You are always exporting the same `ActiveSheet`, you might want to change the sheet you export according to the value of c. Maybe `Sheet(c.Value).ExportAsFixedFormat ...`, but not sure since you didn't explained what the contents of inputrange is.

Comment: The drop down list has company names. And when a new company is selected from the list, the page updates with that companies information. So I am always working with Sheet1 which will always be the ActiveSheet. ActiveSheet is the only method so far that produces the sheet on a pdf the trouble is it apparently doesn't loop through the list as is only ever gives the first companies' info?

Comment: Your code doesn't update the sheet because it doesn't update the choice made in the combobox, you are only running through the values available in the combobox. You can try to update the value of AD5 cell and calculate the sheet for each value before exporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code corresponding to my last comment.
It should retrieve the validation values (the values from the ComboBox) and change the value in [AD5] for each possible value, and then compute the sheet and export it.

```
Sub Create_pdf_pack()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("AD5").Validation.Formula1)
    For Each c In inputRange
        [AD5] = c.Value
        'you might need to refresh the sheet here
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            fileName:="C:\test\" & c.Value, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir :) an additional question if I may though! if i wanted to modify this to save the active sheet as a new excel workbook. I have tried ActiveSheet.SaveAs fileformat:=52, filename:=...... etc but get an error of "Object required?

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgot to modify the value of your dropdown list ( variable called c ?). This value is read and added into the pdf name, but not modified.

As it is now, in the for loop there is only one instruction for creating pdf, therefore, it is the only action performed.

Try to add a modification of the field into the loop.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your coding should work if the *Data Validation* has been set up to support it.  It is easy to verify this.
If I set up *DV* like:

[image]

and run this shortened version of your code:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range, msg As String

    Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("AD5").Validation.Formula1)

    msg = inputRange.Address & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    For Each c In inputRange
        msg = msg & c.Address & vbTab & "C:\test\" & c.Value & vbCrLf
    Next c
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

I get:

[image]

**Try my short program first.**

**EDIT#1:**

From your comments, try replacing:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
```

with:

```
c.ExportAsFixedFormat _
```

**EDIT#2:**

We may be getting close.  I am thinking that each **c** represents a **single cell** in the *DV* list and that each **c** contains the address of the block of cells to be exported.  If that is the case then replace:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
```

with the lines:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(c.Text)
    rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
```

Comment: I get the same thing but with my values. I am thinking that the problem is that whilst selecting the next value in the drop down list, it may not be activating/refreshing the sheet. Is there a way to "activate/refresh" the page after the next item from the list is selected? or would perhaps saving the sheet after selection work?

Comment: @IIJHFII  Your code export the **entire sheet** fifty times.........you are not exporting a range **within** the sheet!

Comment: oh!. the cell AD5 in my sheet is a drop down list where each item changes the values in Sheet1 of my workbook. The plan is to export Sheet1 for each of the values in the drop down list! How could I modify the code for that purpose?

Comment: @IIJHFII  See my **EDIT1**

Comment: Unfortunately c.ExportAsFixedFormat just prints a pdf with the value of c from the list. I then tried c.Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat but this also does not print the Sheet 1 worksheet. The dropdown list is in sheet 1 which is why i though Active.Worksheet would work. Is there a line of code to essentially "refresh" the page after selecting the c value? btw i really appreciate your help thus far :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you:

```
        Public mainSheets(3) As String

    Public Function setMainSheets()
        mainSheets(0) = "sheet1"
        mainSheets(1) = "sheet2"
        mainSheets(2) = "sheet3"
    End Function

    Public Function hasMainSheet(search As String, arrey As Variant) As Boolean
      hasMainSheet = (UBound(Filter(arrey, search)) > -1)
    End Function

    function yourFunction()
    setMainSheets
        For Each plan In Worksheets
                If (Not hasMainSheet(plan.Name, mainSheets)) Then
    your code here
    end if
    next
end function
```